# Windows 8 / Ubuntu in GRUB

Tags: grub2, windows-8

I had problem with mounting "Windows disk" in ubuntu, I have solved this. But now I need help with GRUB. I can't boot Windows by selecting windows drive because I have installed GRUB on all disks. So, is there any way to add Windows into grub menu?

Comment: try boot-repair.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - Didn't helped.

Comment: upload boot-repair log.

Comment: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6534854/ Here it is.

Comment: plz upload gparted screenshot to imgur.com and post the link here.

Comment: both sda and sdb.

Comment: what is your /dev/sdb? Its your internal hard-disk or external hard-disk.

Comment: @AvinashRaj - http://i.imgur.com/q7gWQmT.png - This is my Ubuntu disk; http://i.imgur.com/0klIrSL.png - This my W8 disk.

Comment: what is your /dev/sdb? Its your internal hard-disk or external hard-disk

Comment: @AvinashRaj Both are internal

Comment: turn off secure boot and then try boot-repair

Comment: what was the output of `sudo os-prober`

Comment: @AvinashRaj How can I turn it of please?? No output.

Comment: you need to select recommend repair using repair boot. It would fix it.

Comment: @Braiam - I have tried, it didn't fixed it. :/

Comment: "No change has been performed on your computer." the log says you didn't, who you think I believe?

Comment: @Braiam Lol, whatever log says, I have truth, I'm sure!

Comment: @Braiam Lol.. Really strange http://paste.ubuntu.com/6535257/ this log don't says same, brb going to restart

Comment: Windows still not showing up

Answer (score 0):

You need to repair windows boot for grub to find it, lets see the relevant log:

```
00000190  64 69 73 6b 20 72 65 61  64 20 65 72 72 6f 72 20  |disk read error |
000001a0  6f 63 63 75 72 72 65 64  00 0d 0a 42 4f 4f 54 4d  |occurred...BOOTM|
000001b0  47 52 20 69 73 20 6d 69  73 73 69 6e 67 00 0d 0a  |GR is missing...|
000001c0  42 4f 4f 54 4d 47 52 20  69 73 20 63 6f 6d 70 72  |BOOTMGR is compr|
000001d0  65 73 73 65 64 00 0d 0a  50 72 65 73 73 20 43 74  |essed...Press Ct|
000001e0  72 6c 2b 41 6c 74 2b 44  65 6c 20 74 6f 20 72 65  |rl+Alt+Del to re|
000001f0  73 74 61 72 74 0d 0a 00  8c a9 be d6 00 00 55 aa  |start.........U.|
```

Once you fix your windows boot, repair grub and you most likely will be done.

Comment: Is there any way to repair it without using install dvd or usb ?

Comment: @Danny no, you need to repair the boot.

Comment: Couldn't repair it with Windows Disk .. it says something like windows disk is locked.

Comment: that is windows fault. You must fix windows.

Comment: I think only way to fix it is reinstall whole win.. f%#k